# Question about ReplacePart

Tags: replacement

This is a question about ReplacePart but if there's a better that's great.

If I have a list

```
a= {1,2,3,4,5}
```

and I want to replace elements `1,3,5` with elements `a,b,c` from list `{a,b,c}`, can I use ReplaceParts to do this in one step?

I have only been able to do this replacing one element at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: list /. {1 -> a, 3 -> b, 5 -> c}

Comment: @Hubble07: You are saying that if the first list contains 1000 elements and the second list contains 500 that I would have to type 1->a, etc. 500 times?

Comment: Isn't there some way to use a list of indices and replacement elements and do this all at once?

Comment: you have names conflict, `a` is a list and an element of the last list. p.s. does this work for you: `list /. Thread[{1,2,3}->{a,b,c}]`?

Comment: for this specific case you can use a[[;; ;; 2]]= {aa,b,c}. I have changed a to aa because of name conflict as kuba mentioned.

Comment: @Algohi, thanks that seems to work too.

Comment: @Algohi I didn't see your comment until after I posted my answer, which includes that method and times.  I think part assignment is the best way.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you are the master here and no one can talk in your presence. Thank you for your comment and for your great answer :)

Comment: @Algohi Not sure what I should say to that.  I don't consider myself a master and I hope I never hold you back from posting an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard not at all. I did not plan to post an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest *not* using [`ReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html) but [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) assignment or [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html) instead.

Three functions to compare:

```
repOdd1[old_, new_] := ReplacePart[old, Thread[Range[1, Length@old, 2] -> new]]

repOdd2[old_, new_] := Module[{x = old}, x[[;; ;; 2]] = new; x]

repOdd3[old_, new_] := Riffle[new, old[[2 ;; ;; 2]]]
```

Test:

```
a = Range@9;
b = {q, r, s, t, u};

repOdd1[a, b]
repOdd2[a, b]
repOdd3[a, b]
```

> ```
> {q, 2, r, 4, s, 6, t, 8, u}
>
> {q, 2, r, 4, s, 6, t, 8, u}
>
> {q, 2, r, 4, s, 6, t, 8, u}
> ```

Performance:

```
a = Range@999999;
b = Range[1000001, 1500000];

repOdd1[a, b] // AbsoluteTiming // First
repOdd2[a, b] // AbsoluteTiming // First
repOdd3[a, b] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.052060
>
> 0.002000
>
> 0.008001
> ```

Both `Part` and `Riffle` are orders of magnitude faster than `ReplacePart`.  `Part` assignment is a bit more verbose than `Riffle` if we include `Module` but also faster and applicable for in-place modification should that be desired.

`Part` also works for an arbitrary index list, not only an evenly spaced [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html):

```
(* in-place modification in this example *)

a = Range@9;
b = {q, r, s, t, u};
a[[{1, 2, 9, 7, 5}]] = b;
a
```

> ```
> {q, r, 3, 4, u, 6, t, 8, s}
> ```

I am a fan of using `Part` for many operations: [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns/3077#3077)

Comment: Kuba has not posted his/her answer--what do you think of that suggestion, out of curiosity?

Comment: @daniel By my interpretation of the question that is not a solution.  I am assuming that the list elements `1`, `2`, `3`, are arbitrary, not *always* natural numbers 1..n.

Comment: With that in mind I will accept yours as the more general solution, although because my lists are almost always of numbers Kuba's response was helpful.

Comment: @daniel If you wish to replace by index it will be faster to do that using `Part` assignment.  However if you wish to replace elements by pattern, which is what Kuba's code does, it is not applicable.  These are two different operations with only one intersection: the case where the starting list is Range\[ *n* \].

Answer (score 8):

What about

```
ReplacePart[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, Thread[{1, 3, 5} -> {a, b, c}]]
```

or in general

```
replaceParts[original_, positions_, replacements_] := ReplacePart[
    original,
    Thread[positions -> replacements]
]
```

Comment: Assuming it works, doesn't add a step? Basically in Kuba's note it's just "Thread." Very economical. But if it works, fine.+1

Comment: No. There are two steps in both my example is: ReplacePart[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, Thread[{1, 3, 5} -> {a, b, c}]], while Kuba's is ReplaceAll[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, Thread[{1, 3, 5} -> {a, b, c}]]. Secondly Kuba's only works if the original list is a Range, mine works with any list.

Comment: Inner[Rule,{1,3,5},{a,b,c}] should be faster than Thread[{1, 3, 5} -> {a, b, c}], if speed is a consideration.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer other answers (particularly `Part` if the application permits it), but I will take this opportunity to mention the undocumented four-argument form of `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {a, b, c}, {{1}, {3}, {5}} , {{1}, {2}, {3}}]
(* {a,2,b,4,c} *)
```

This syntax says to replace parts 1, 3, and 5 of `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` with parts 1, 2, and 3 of `{a, b, c}`.  This syntax has been supported for a very long time, but it is undocumented so I suppose it could disappear some day.

Incidentally, and not relevant to the present question, there is also an undocumented three-argument form:

```
ReplacePart[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {a, b, c}, {{1}, {3}, {5}}]
(* {{a,b,c},2,{a,b,c},4,{a,b,c}} *)
```

This form says to replace parts 1, 3, and 5 of `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` with the value `{a, b, c}`.

Comment: I almost posted this myself but I could not see how it simplified the problem so I did not.  You were probably the one I learned it from.  Is this posted elsewhere on site?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I posted here because it is vaguely relevant and I haven't seen it mentioned elsewhere on the site.  There are more posts that use `ReplacePart` than I care to review, so it might be out there somewhere.  I'm pretty sure I've discussed it before somewhere in the StackExchange universe, but it would have been in chat or a comment.

Comment: One reference: [(17344)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17344/121).  Anyway +1 for taking the time to remind us of this nugget even it if doesn't fit perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
ReplacePart[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {i_?OddQ} :> {a, b, c}[[(i + 1)/2]]]
```

> {a, 2, b, 4, c}